# How to create bookmarkable dynamic div tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In gmail, we can see that if we open a mail, the address changes from
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox to this https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/14552c232aa5a9f4
without reloading the whole page, that is i can bookmark the content in a div which is dynamic

```
function load(thediv,thefile) {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else 
   {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState ==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
   }
   xmlhttp.open('GET',thefile,true);
   xmlhttp.send();

 }
```

I have tried this ajax code to load dynamic content to a div...but I can't bookmark it.
how can I do that in my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is calling 'pushstate'. For more information you can see [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/jquery-pusher/) or [this](http://www.frontendjournal.com/html5-pushstate-and-single-page-apps/)